# MS Access 2007: Specify Max Length for TextBox on a Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How do I specify Max Length for TextBox on a Form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you on your way

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-34.html

It covers if users paste into the box and lots of other ways making it very useful

Answer (score 2):

You can use validation rules.
Open the Property Sheet of the Form -> Tab 'Data' and fill out 'validation rule' with e.g.: 
`Len([fieldname])<=42 Or Is Null`

You can also add a 'validation text' like: "Maximum 42 chars allowed!"